# Failed Importing Cyrillic (UTF8) json file into MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, windows-10, cyrillic, mongoimport

**Question**: How to use mongoimport.exe utility to import UTF8 json documents with Cyrillic chars into mongodb database under MS Windows 10? ([mongoimport.exe online docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) do not provide any information or I'm missing it?)

**Environment**: MS Windows 10, MongoDB 3.2.3, mongoimport.exe

**Source UTF8 json file**:

```
{
  "PersonnelNumber": "15128",
  "OrderNumber": "765-01",
  "OrderDate": "2011-05-04T00:00:00",
  "JobPosition": "Слесарь по ремонту подвижного состава"
}
```

**Command line**:

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongoimport.exe" --db testOrders --collection orders --drop < "TestOrder.json"
```

**Import log**:

```
2016-03-01T14:47:04.350+0300    connected to: localhost
dropping: testOrders.orders
Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'ï' looking for beginning of value
imported 0 documents
```

**Note**

ANSI version of the test file is getting imported without errors but Cyrillic char codes are stored in mongoDb database incorrectly, here is how they are displayed in mongoDb shell:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3
connecting to: testOrders
> db.orders.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d5838aef35e4f7c03e81bd"),
    "PersonnelNumber" : "15128",
    "OrderNumber" : "765-01",
    "OrderDate" : "2011-05-04T00:00:00",
    "JobPosition" : "������� �� ������� ���������� �������"
}
>
```

Here is a screenshot with hex codes of UTF8 and ANSI files:

[image: Screenshot with hex codes of UTF8 and ANSI versions of JSON file]

When using C# driver (VS2015) to list imported by mongoimport.exe utility json file

```
foreach (var order in
   (new MongoClient()).GetDatabase("testOrders")
   .GetCollection<BsonDocument>("orders").FindSync(new BsonDocument()).ToList())
            System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", order.ToString());
```

the test output also has wrong Cyrillic chars:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d5838aef35e4f7c03e81bd"),
    "PersonnelNumber" : "15128",
    "OrderNumber" : "765-01",
    "OrderDate" : "2011-05-04T00:00:00",
    "JobPosition" : "������� �� ������� ���������� �������"
}
```

When using C# driver (VS2015) to insert BsonDocument from C# and then to list imported by mongoimport.exe utility json file/document and the BsonDocument document inserted via C# code

```
var collection = (new MongoClient()).GetDatabase("testOrders")
                         .GetCollection<BsonDocument>("orders");

var document = new BsonDocument
{
  {"PersonnelNumber", "15128" },
  {"OrderNumber", "765-01"},
  {"OrderDate", "2011-05-04T00:00:00"},
  {"JobPosition", "Слесарь по ремонту подвижного состава"}
};
collection.InsertOne(document);

foreach (var order in collection.FindSync(new BsonDocument()).ToList())
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", order.ToString());
```

the former has incorrect Cyrillic chars and the latter has correct Cyrillic chars:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56d5838aef35e4f7c03e81bd"),
  "PersonnelNumber" : "15128",
  "OrderNumber" : "765-01",
  "OrderDate" : "2011-05-04T00:00:00",
  "JobPosition" : "������� �� ������� ���������� �������"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56d58c5c1ed24820b80b80f6"),
  "PersonnelNumber" : "15128",
  "OrderNumber" : "765-01",
  "OrderDate" : "2011-05-04T00:00:00",
  "JobPosition" : "Слесарь по ремонту подвижного состава"
}
```

Comment: You're 100% certain the JSON file is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: @deceze: yes, please verify, I have just added a screenshot with hex codes of the sources UTF8 and ANSI versions of my test json file